# "Animation" in CSS3 not working in mozilla. What to do?

Tags: html, css

I have used keyframe of css3 but in case of mozilla its not working. It is working fine with google chrome.

I used both @keyframe and @-webkit-keyframe, also same with "animation". but its not working I don't know why.

Comment: Can you post your exact code please?

Comment: Some sample code...? We have almost nothing to go on. You could try taking a look at the CSS properties in Firebug. Chances are, it's expecting a certain property name differently from the one you're using, and will either omit it, or display it with a 'strikethru'.

Comment: actually...
I am just using...
`
<div>
....
animation:animate 5s linear infinite;
-webkit-animation:animate 5s linear infinite;
....
}

@keyframe animate{
/* some animation*/
}
@-webkit-keyframe animate{
/* some animation*/
}`

Comment: When you say "Mozilla" do you mean FireFox?  [Mozilla hasn't been a stand-alone browser for quite some time now](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Application_Suite).  What versions of the browsers are you using?

Comment: yes I am using firefox

Comment: What version of FireFox are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You should be specifying mozilla **(moz)** as well like below:

```
@-webkit-keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Comment: I found on w3school.com that using -webkit- we can also work on mozilla thats why I was not using it.. But it is working thanks anyway

Comment: @CDnDT W3Schools is a great starting point, but has a long history of having spotty accuracy.

Comment: Let me know some great website for css3 tutorial

Comment: Well, for reference, no one beats [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS).  They're all about the latest specs.  If you want tutorials you may want to check out [CodeSChool](http://www.codeschool.com/), but I find the best way to stay on top of my CSS game is to read blogs that focus on the subject, and to make sure I understand everything I include.

Comment: If you found my response helpful please mark my answer as accepted. Thanks. Glad you figured it out.